# Having two solutions, one without Nuget packages and one with Nuget packages

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

My original Solution is just two projects, one for the actual project and one for the Tests. So most of the time that's all I need to work. and everything is in `TFS`
But it is referencing some other libraries that we have written and I am using them from their `Nuget` packages and sometimes I need to debug my project with those `Nuget` projects included so I can step through the code. So I have to remove my references, add the `Nuget` projects one by one, do the debug, now revert it back etc..

So I was wondering is there a way I can keep two copies of my solution? One that just references the `Nuget` ones and one that does include them in the solution for the times I need to debug them and step through them?

Comment: You could use a symbol server to distribute the debug information for the libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question: you can create a branch for your project, and then you can use the original solution for actual and new branch for test or versa. When you have code changes in one branch, you can then merge it to another one.

However, the better solution for your situation is just as oɔɯǝɹ mentioned in the comments, configure a symbol server to store the debug information for your nuget libraries.

Comment: They just have given permission of creating branches in TFS to managers here !! I can't create one ( LOL I am not kidding! ) .
So what is a symbol server?  Is it something we do on the server? or I can do on my machine ?

Comment: @Bohn You can refer to this link for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680693(v=vs.85).aspx. By the way, I forget to mentioned that Nuget also support create and publish a symbol package for debugging, you can refer to this link for details: https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-symbol-package